# I'm running ubuntu12.04. Lost wireless connection then lost wired connection

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking

I've been searching the internet for some answers but can't seem to find any specifics. I tried changing the Network Manager file from "false" to "true" but I could not get rid of "ifupdown(eth0)". Also, when I tried to open firefox I got "server not found". So, I tried to remove it and reinstall it and I got a message "Couldn't resolve host 'Launchpad.net'". What is going on and how can I fix it? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove ifupdown(eth0) go to /etc/network/

```
sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

and **delete all entries in there except for auto lo / iface lo inet loopback**.

T

```
he following lines

   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
have to be the only entries present in /etc/network/interfaces.
```

Next you should edit another file located in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf.

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

L**ook for this entry [ifupdown] and edit the entry to look like this**:

```
 [ifupdown]
   managed=false
```

Reboot and reconfigure if necessary your network using the network applet from system tray.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for my wired connection. I would like to get my wireless going too. Also, there is still the issue with "Couldn't resolve host 'launchpad.net'" when trying to install firefox. Have any ideas?